# Creating Toolbar Items That Look Like Buttons

Tags: macos, cocoa

I can't seem to figure out how to make my toolbar items look like buttons.  Some examples of what I'm looking for are the toolbar items in Mail, Safari and Transmission.  Are these buttons just simple images, or is there a setting somewhere I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They *are* NSButtons or NSSegmentedControls. Just drag one right into the toolbar from the IB palette.

Comment: Ha, I was trying to drag them onto the toolbar instead of to the "Allowed Toolbar Items" area.  I feel kind of dumb now.  Thanks for the help.